# List as function argument

Tags: functions

I have a problem when using a list as argument of a function. When I use only a single number, the result is OK but when I use a list, the result is wrong and I have this error message I can't understand.

Could someone help me ? :)

```
 Iinit = ( # * 1.6 * 10^-27 * (5.3 * 10^-11)^2) & /@ {
   283.33202, 785.40751, 1050.86046
 }
```

> ```
> {1.27341*10^-45, 3.52994*10^-45, 4.72299*10^-45}
> ```

```
Q = (((2*k*#)/(h/(2*π))^2)^(3/2)*(π*Times @@@ {Iinit})^(1/2)) &
```

> ```
> ((2 k #1)/(h/(2 π))^2)^(3/2) Sqrt[π Apply[Times, {Iinit}, {1}]] &
> ```

```
T = Range[990, 995]
```

> ```
> {990, 991, 992, 993, 994, 995}
> ```

```
Q[990]
```

> ```
> {995278.}
> ```

```
Q[T]
```

> During evaluation of In[196]:= Thread::tdlen: Objects of unequal length in {3.85384*10^72,3.85968*10^72,3.86553*10^72,3.87137*10^72,3.87722*10^72,3.88308*10^72} {2.58256*10^-67} cannot be combined.
>
> ```
> {2.58256*10^-67} {3.85384*10^72, 3.85968*10^72, 
>   3.86553*10^72, 3.87137*10^72, 3.87722*10^72, 3.88308*10^72}
> ```

Comment: I'm sorry, in my code, Iinit is I.....

Comment: When there's a problem like this, try to construct a minimal example. During that process, you will discover the problem on your own in most cases. Here's a minimal example for this case: `{1,2,3}^2` works but `{1,2,3}^{2}` does not. It is not valid to operate together lists of different lengths.

Comment: Why would you want a list with just one value in your `Q` function?

Comment: What are `h` and `k`?

Comment: Have you tried `Q /@ T`?

Comment: @m_goldberg : h and k are just some constant. What is the difference between Q[T] and Q /@ T ? I'm sorry, I'm a beginer with Mathematica and my questions may seems very basic...

Comment: Following the corrected definition given in my answer below there is no difference between `Q[T]` and `Q /@T` (short notation for `Map`), as `T` being a vector in a function with scalars will give a vector of results. Mapping `Q` will also give a vector of results but then `#` (the slot) will be filled by the components of `T` so that Q will work on a scalar (one component) and will be called many times.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the result of the partial expression within your `Q` function:

```
Times @@@ {Iinit}
```

> {2.123*10^-134}

It produces a list (e.g. a vector) but what you want for your multiplications seems to be a scalar (why have a list with just one value?), so probably this is what you need:

```
Times @@ Iinit
```

> 2.123*10^-134

Accordingly, when we change the defintiion for `Q` it works out:

```
Q = (((2*k*#)/(h/(2*π))^2)^(3/2)*(π*Times @@ Iinit)^(1/2)) &;

Q[T]
```

> {5.64401*10^-60 (k/h^2)^(3/2), 5.65256*10^-60 (k/h^2)^(3/2), 
>    5.66112*10^-60 (k/h^2)^(3/2), 5.66968*10^-60 (k/h^2)^(3/2), 
>    5.67825*10^-60 (k/h^2)^(3/2), 5.68682*10^-60 (k/h^2)^(3/2)}

Comment: Ok, thank you, I didn't notice this point !

Comment: @JRLCAR Is that what you want? Note, that there will be no difference between `Q[T]` and `Q /@ T` in this case.

Comment: yes, thank you !